# Is there a way to let gradle use a specific ant version?

Tags: ant, build, gradle

I am working with a third party framework that I am integrating gradle into. I am calling some old ant tasks. The problem is that the third party framework wants me to use:

1. either its own ant, that is packaged with it
2. a specific ant version, in this case 1.9.1

Unfortunately there is no way to set the ant version that is used by gradle. I can not figure out if its is possible to point gradle to any specific version within my environment.

So what do you think I could do?

Thanks in advance,

Denis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use a different Ant version than the one that comes with Gradle, you'll have to call out to Ant via a `JavaExec` or `Exec` task, rather than using Gradle's built-in Ant support.

Comment: Sound like a good idea, its may be even better for my case. In the meanwhile I created my own gradle distribution zip with the needed ant version and it works.

Comment: I've the same problem. What did you exaclty create/change the default Gradle distribution zip? Thanks (is it hybris what you use? :)